# Subscribe to all messages from NServiceBus

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I'd like to subscribe to all messages being sent across the NServiceBus system, for the purpose of logging and monitoring.  However trying to listen for IMessage doesn't work, ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NServiceBus has explicit support for auditing through the ForwardReceivedMessagesTo configuration option. Have your admins configure each of your endpoints to forward the messages to a central audit queue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write to the event log in all your IMessageHandler implementations.
2. Get SCOM to monitor the event logs.